# Changing one navigation bar to transparent changes all navigation bars to transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation controller embedded to the first view of my app.

When I change the navigation bar to transparent on one view it changes it to transparent to all views and I cannot seem to change it back.

I would like it to be transparent for a few of my Views but not all.

To set to transparent I use:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code that changes the Navigation Bar's background colour in `viewWillAppear`, and then change the colour back to default in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: I will try it out! What code would change it back to default? Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to make it not transparent, try `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false`

Comment: This worked. However I left the code in viewDidLoad and set the color back to default in viewDidDisappear! It works in viedDidAppear but it just takes a second to load. Thanks!

Comment: using `viewDidLoad` and then `viewDidDisappear` is a bit precarious - because if the view disappears without unloading, and then you go back to the view (this all depends on your navigation flow), you could wind up not having the transparent bar when you expected to have it.   If `viewDidAppear` is loading too slow, try `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`. If you still like `viewDidLoad` better, than probably better to use `viewDidUnload`

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` is common for all view controllers in this hierarchy , if you want to change translucency for some viewcontrollers then change that in particular controller's `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing? I've already placed that code in viewDidLoad. Thanks!

Comment: in which controller you are placing this code,  that working fine or not ?

Comment: In the first 4. It works perfectly but the problem is that it makes all navigation bars in any controller transparent and I can't change them to the color I want. But yeah the code works well

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

hope its helpful